# Segmentation fault on pushing anything to stack

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

I was trying to run the assembly subroutine written in x86 assembly at&t syntax. But whenever I try to push anything to the stack, I get segmentation fault

assembly.s

```
.global foo
foo:
    push $1
```

code.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern void foo();

int main(){
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
default:
    rm -f assembly.o code.o
    as -32 assembly.s -o assembly.o
    gcc -m32 -c code.c -o code.o
    gcc -m32 code.o assembly.o -o prog
    ./prog
```

Comment: Do you know how `ret` works? It pops the return address from the stack. So if you `push $1` the `ret` will try to go to address `1` which is invalid, hence the fault. You should balance the stack before trying to return, e.g. `pop %eax` or `add $4, %esp`.

Comment: @Jester The segmentation fault persists even on removing ret and making foo a void function. (I have updated the description)

Comment: @Jester any add/subtract operation on esp is giving me segmentation fault.

Comment: did you put a `$` sign before the value being added to ESP?

Comment: Even `void` functions need the `ret`. It is not for returning a value (it doesn't do that) it's for transferring the control back to the caller. `push $1; pop %eax; ret` should work.

Comment: @Jester Thanks a lot, it worked. Now I get it what ret does.

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes I  did. I got the mistake, anyway thanks for helping.